# What javascript methods are available in mongo?

Tags: mongo-shell

This is a general question and what i'm looking for here is a link to some resource.

Explanation:

I recently figured out how to run a mongo shell script (refer to this post: [can't make basic mongo shell script with authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389424/cant-make-basic-mongo-shell-script-with-authentication/26391836#26391836)) and in doing this i realized that the javascript methods available via the mongo shell are not the same as the ones i use in the browser.  So my question is, where can i find a list of all available methods?

Please also note that i have already looked here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ While this is useful it is clearly not a complete list because it doesn't include the core javascript functionality such as for loops and methods like printjson().

Answer (score 1):

The mongo shell is built on the JavaScript V8 engine so all basic JavaScript functionality available in Node.js is available in the Mongo shell (mongo university M101JS, week 1, lecture 8: Introduction to the Mongo Shell).

You've found the core functionality document which is fairly complete but does not explain how to use things like the admin commands. You can find a list of those here: http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/command/nav-administration/